# advice for transforming data gathered from screen scrapers

Tags: database, screen-scraping, web-crawler, transform

good day folks,

I have my screen scraper (scrapy) collecting data of property listings on several property websites. They all have several common fields like price, floor area etc. However, like all scraped data, the values for the fields are rather undesirable right now. For instance, in `price`, I have obvious values like `$1,000,000,000`, but I also have stuff like `$1,000,000,000 Price on Ask` and `Price on Ask`. So currently, I stored all my scraped fields as char in my database.

I would like to transform these string fields in my database from characters to the appropriate type e.g string to int, so I can index them accordingly. Can someone offer me some advice what would be sensible procedure and method to begin transforming the data?

Answer (score 1):

You want to throw away the "Price On Ask" string? Or is that valuable information?

If there is a lot of noise in the data, and it is all of no-interest, I'd run a filter to remove all non-digits.

But, if time allows, I prefer to process the data explicitly with pattern matching (sample code is PHP):

```
//$price is raw string
$price=str_replace(',','',$price);    //Get rid of commas
$price=str_replace('$','',$price);    //Get rid of dollar signs

if($price=='Price On Ask')$price=null;
elseif(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$price))$price=(int)$price;  //Simple number
elseif(preg_match('/^(\d+) Price On Ask$/i',$price,$parts)){
   $price=(int)$parts[1];
   }
else{
   echo "Unexpected price string: $price\n";
   $price=null;
   }
```

I then have the structure to set flags for some of the strings. Also, when a new string appears in the data my script gets noisy and I can decide if it matters or not.

(Note: setting $price to null implies putting a NULL in the database, not a zero.)